# storing bank account numbers

Tags: php, mysql, security

I need to store bank account information (account numbers and routing numbers) in order to send them payment.

What solution do you guys suggest to be able to store these securely? I really don't want to store them in the mysql database without some form of encryption!

Is there a service that allows storing of bank account and other sensitive information that makes this information easily retrievable when needed?

Comment: one solution http://www-03.ibm.com/security/cryptocards/

Comment: Besides any technical requirements you may have, there may also be some legal requirements in your country relating to the storage of banking details.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the mcrypt php library: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

It will allow you to encrypt information and then store it anywhere you want. (mysql, text, etc.)

Make sure you use SSL (https) for transmitting the information from your web server to the client.